# How do I disable XSS/"Same Origin" checking on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, xss

I am trying to access the contents of HTML tags within an iframe on a page I am developing. The parent and iframed pages have the same root domain, but different subdomains. I cannot alter the iframed page, but I can alter the parent page.

To this end, I opened Chrome via

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
```

to let Chrome ignore the Same Origin Policy pertinent to accessing elements in an Iframe. However, Chrome still returns an error when I try to access the elements of the Iframe:

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

How do I tell Chrome to completely ignore XSS checking? Can I use command line arguments? This page on Dropbox illustrates my intention. I am trying to access the contents of the iframe. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/Misc/subDomainFrameAccess/index.html

Comment: You don’t do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X-frame-options is anti-clickjacking, not XSS. The page refuses to be displayed in an iframe. Can you use a popup window instead?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I don't think I can use a popup since I'm scraping data off of a web page. Nonetheless, I've resorted to manually recording data.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment on the chrome bug list so the chrome devs hear our collective cries!

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=857032